# Facebook profile link of some facebook user is declined in response using FBSDKLoginManager in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbsdkloginkit

I'm using **FBSDKLoginKit** to **login with Facebook**. I'm trying to get **email**, **name**, **public profile** and **user profile link**. According to **latest policy** to get **profile link**, developer need to ask **permission** during login and should provide how the information are being used to Facebook for **review**. I did all those process.

I was able to get all those required parameters when login with **my developer Facebook account** using **FBSDKLoginManager**. But when I tried login with another user account, **profile link was declined in response**. The link was empty.

I've created a method as below to login and get those parameters.

```
- (void)loginFaceBook
{
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount;
    // need permission

    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_link"]
                 fromViewController:self
                            handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
     {

         if (error)
         {
             NSLog(@"Process error"); 
         }
         else if (result.isCancelled)
         {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Logged in");

             if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
             {
                 NSDictionary *params = @{@"fields" : @"id,name,link,email"};

                 [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:params]
                  startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id responseData, NSError *error)
                  {
                       NSLog(@"%@",responseData);
                      if (!error)
                      {
                          NSString *fbEmail = [AQCommon validateTextBeforePack:[responseData objectForKey:kEmail]];
                          NSString *fblink = [AQCommon validateTextBeforePack:[responseData objectForKey:@"link"]];
                          NSString *fbname = [AQCommon validateTextBeforePack:[responseData objectForKey:@"name"]];


                      }
                      else
                      {
                          NSLog(@"Facebook login failed. Please try later.");                  }
                      }
                  }];
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"Facebook login failed. Please try later.");                  }

         }

     }];
}
```

I got all the required parameters login with my Facebook developer account (where I've created my app), but **user_link** was **declined for some other accounts**. What could be the problem? Is it related to Facebook privacy policy? Or, user needs to change some settings in their profile?

**Apart from the above problem**, the profile link that I got of my developer account was **opening from any Facebook account except some accounts**. The error says either the link is expired or permission is not granted. **The problem is very specific to Facebook user accounts. What could be the reasons and solutions?**

Comment: You need to get your app’s use of most permissions reviewed by Facebook, before you can ask normal users for them. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Comment: Thank you @CBroe. So, once the review is approved by Facebook, it will start working right?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook provides sandboxed test users which can use be used for testing purposes.

Here you can check all about Facebook test users.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what should be done for the real Facebook users? Is there something wrong in my code or I missed some steps ? Could you please clarify me?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that facebook allow to see the profile only if the user is friend or friend of friend.